# CSS infline-flex: text overlap

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a `footer` with my name on the left side and my `home` , `portfolio`, and `contact` links on the right. But my links overlap with each other and I don't know what's causing this. I have tried `justify-content:space-around` but they still overlap, and I am completely stuck since I am new to CSS.

Picture of problem
[image: Picture of problem]

HTML:

```
<div class="footer-nav">
        <h3>Name</h3>
        <ul class='nav'>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>

        </ul> 
    </div> <!-- end of div class "footer-nav"-->
```

CSS:

```
.footer-nav {
    border-top: 1px solid lightgrey;
    padding: 1.5625em 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.footer-nav h3 {
    display: inline-flex;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding-right: 6.7em;
    list-style-type: none;

}
.nav{
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a margin, and try this:

```css
.footer-nav {
  border-top: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 1.5625em 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.footer-nav h3 {
  display: inline-flex;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding-right: 6.7em;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}

li {
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-nav">
  <h3>Name</h3>
  <ul class='nav'>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>

  </ul>
</div>
<!-- end of div class "footer-nav"-->
```